# Our RAM usage is high, including -/+ buffer/cache, but top has no answers

Tags: centos, php, memory, top, memory-leak

We are running CentOS 6 with a PHP web application.

After we pushed a new version live it seems we have a memory issue, however `top` does not show any high usage instances. I have looked around and people suggest checking out `free`, to check if it is just being used by the cache. The result shows that it is being used up by processes other than cache.

[image: scout.io]
[image: top]
[image: free]
[image: meminfo]

I would like to know which direction to start looking in, and any suggestions if there are any.

Many Thanks
- Matt

Comment: Do you have an actual problem or is this issue purely cosmetic?

Comment: What is the output of `ps -eo rss,vsz,pid,cmd  --sort -rss,-vsz`

Comment: In addition to the information @sciurus requested, you need to ask yourself "What changed on or about October 21?" (You say you pushed a "new version" of your code -- what did the developers *do*? Do their changes explain this behavior? Is this an expected consequence, or a bug that needs to be fixed? If it's an expected consequence, will you need to adjust your capacity planning based on the new version of the code?)

Comment: Provide the output of `cat /proc/meminfo`

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Yes, the server also runs other websites, and it seems this problem causes assets to timeout when requesting (images, scripts etc)

Answer (score 2):

You should have the developers test their code (specifically the code that changed in this new version) and measure the memory usage. Tools like the [xdebug profiler](http://xdebug.org/docs/profiler) (you can use [webgrind](https://code.google.com/p/webgrind/), [phpstorm](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Profiling+PHP+applications+with+PhpStorm+and+Xdebug), [qcachegrind](http://sourceforge.net/projects/qcachegrindwin/)/[kcachegrind](http://kcachegrind.sourceforge.net/html/Home.html) to read the results) and (maybe more importantly) [xhprof](http://pecl.php.net/package/xhprof), as it also collects memory metrics. You can use tools like [preinheimer/xhprof](https://github.com/preinheimer/xhprof) or [perftools/xhgui](https://github.com/perftools/xhgui) to visualize that data.